# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to plot Ph and Pu for the time range of 0 to 300 with time step of 0.01. But, while running this code, it is showing the error as stated in the title of this question. Please give your suggestions for the code below

```
Pu = (np.zeros((1,Nt)))
Ph = (np.zeros((1,Nt)))

dec = 0.01 *2 * np.pi

Pu[1] = 1

for i in range(2, Nt):
        Pu[i] = dt * (-(dec) * Pu[i-1] + Pu[i-1])
return Pu

Ph[1] = 0
for i in range(2, Nt):
        Ph[i] = dt * ((dec) * Pu[i-1] - kappa * 1e-12 * Ph[i-1] + Ph[i-1])
return Ph
```

> **Statement which is showing error:
>       Pu[1] = 1
>
> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: just for your next posts, you can add code starting with tree times ` and also ending with tree times `

Answer (score 0):

I see several mistakes here:

First, you will want to remove the parenthesis here:
`Pu = (np.zeros((1,Nt)))`
creates a tuple containing a numpy array, whereas: 
`Pu = np.zeros((1,Nt))`
simply creates the numpy array you need.

Then, your array is of size (1,Nt) so in the for loop you should do:
`Pu[0,i]=...`, same goes for the other arrays.

Finally be careful, arrays in python starts at index 0 so the first element is `Pu[0,0]` and the last is `Pu[0,Nt-1]`.

In addition, you should be just fine with `Pu=np.zeros(Nt)` it seems you do not require a 2D array here (and it you simply access its elements with P[i]).